# Get custom field in Kohana 2.3

Tags: php, kohana

I have a Kohana 2.3 application.  For the logged in/authenticated user I would like to lookup
the a field that I have added to the users table called radius_username.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this just to get it working.  Although, I suspect it's long winded.

I happen to have the current username in the variable *$this->username*

```
$user = ORM::factory('user')->where('username', $this->username)->find();
```

Now the radius username can be gotten with:

```
$user->radius_username
```